# How to display view within a sheet programmatically in SwiftUI?

Tags: google-maps, swiftui, google-maps-sdk-ios, infowindow, gmsmapview

I am currently using Google Maps API in SwiftUI, and am trying to get a sheet to appear after a marker infoWindow is tapped programmatically.

In other parts of my app I’m displaying sheets like this, and it’s the same thing I’m trying to achieve here but programmatically:

```
https://blog.kaltoun.cz/swiftui-presenting-modal-sheet/
```

Right now I have a function that prints a message when an infoWindow is tapped, but don’t know how to make a SwiftUI view appear within a sheet using the function.

-

Since I’m using SwiftUI, the way I implement the Google Maps API is a little different than in plain Swift.
Here are the basics of my GMView.swift file that handles all the google maps stuff.

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
import CoreLocation
import Foundation



struct GoogMapView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GoogMapControllerRepresentable()
    }
}


class GoogMapController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate {
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var mapView: GMSMapView!
    let defaultLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 42.361145, longitude: -71.057083)
    var zoomLevel: Float = 15.0
    let marker : GMSMarker = GMSMarker()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 50
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.delegate = self

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: defaultLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: defaultLocation.coordinate.longitude, zoom: zoomLevel)
        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: view.bounds, camera: camera)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.setMinZoom(14, maxZoom: 20)
        mapView.settings.compassButton = true
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        mapView.settings.scrollGestures = true
        mapView.settings.zoomGestures = true
        mapView.settings.rotateGestures = true
        mapView.settings.tiltGestures = true
        mapView.isIndoorEnabled = false


        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.361145, longitude: -71.057083)
        marker.title = "Boston"
        marker.snippet = "USA"
        marker.map = mapView

        // Add the map to the view, hide it until we&#39;ve got a location update.
        view.addSubview(mapView)
//        mapView.isHidden = true

    }

    // Handle incoming location events.
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
      let location: CLLocation = locations.last!
      print("Location: \(location)")

      let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude, zoom: zoomLevel)

      if mapView.isHidden {
        mapView.isHidden = false
        mapView.camera = camera
      } else {
        mapView.animate(to: camera)
      }

    }

    // Handle authorization for the location manager.
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
      switch status {
      case .restricted:
        print("Location access was restricted.")
      case .denied:
        print("User denied access to location.")
        // Display the map using the default location.
        mapView.isHidden = false
      case .notDetermined:
        print("Location status not determined.")
      case .authorizedAlways: fallthrough
      case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        print("Location status is OK.")
      }
    }

    // Handle location manager errors.
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
      locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
      print("Error: \(error)")
    }

}


struct GoogMapControllerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<GMControllerRepresentable>) -> GMController {
        return GMController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: GMController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<GMControllerRepresentable>) {

    }
}
```

Here is the function I'm putting within GMView.swift's UIViewController (GMController) that I’m trying to use to make a view appear within a sheet:

```
// Function to handle when a marker's infowindow is tapped
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf didTapInfoWindowOfMarker: GMSMarker) {
        print("You tapped a marker's infowindow!")
        return
    }
```

Here is the view I’m trying to get to appear:

```
struct SortBy: View {
    var body: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Sort By")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.black)
                .padding(.trailing, 6)
            Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        }

    }
}
```

**Does anyone know how I can get my function above to make a SwiftUI view appear within a sheet?**

Comment: The way to do it in your SwiftUI code add a @EnvironmentObject variable and check if it is true. If it is true show a sheet. In your MapView didSelect set this variable to true, Set it to false in your SwiftUI code when dismissing the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Use .sheet similarly like here:

https://blog.appsbymw.com/posts/how-to-present-and-dismiss-a-modal-in-swiftui-155c/

Comment: That's similar to the link I referenced above and used to make other modals appear. But if i add this code to my View ```.sheet(isPresented: self.$show_modal) {
         ModalView()
        }```, how would I make the function I have within the UIViewController toggle the variable within the View to show the modal?

Answer (score 0):

You will need:

1. In your `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, add a `State` object, let's say `@State var showModal = false`
2. In your parent view, Use `.sheet(isPresented: $showModal) { CONTENT_VIEW(showModal: $showModal) }`
3. In your `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, also add a Binding for `showModal` .
4. In your `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, use `Coordinator` to set your `UIViewController` and `GMSMapViewDelegate`
5. In your UIViewController, Now you can access the Binding via  `owner.showModal`

Hope it helps. Good luck.